# Renaming columns according to vector inside pipe

Tags: r, pipe

I have a data.frame `df` with columns `A` and `B`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 11:15)
```

There's another data.frame, `df2`, which I'm building by various calculations that ends up having generic column names X1 and X2, which I cannot control directly (because it passes through being a matrix at one point). So it ends up being something like:

```
mtrx <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
mtrx %>% data.frame()
```

I would like to rename the columns in df2 to be the same as df. I could, of course, do it after I finish building df2 with a simple assigning:

```
names(df2)<-names(df)
```

My question is - is there a way to do this directly within the pipe? I can't seem to use dplyr::rename, because these have to be in the form of newname=oldname, and I can't seem to vectorize it. Same goes to the `data.frame` call itself - I can't just give it a vector of column names, as far as I can tell. Is there another option I'm missing? What I'm hoping for is something like

```
mtrx %>% data.frame() %>% rename(names(df))
```

but this doesn't work - gives error `Error: All arguments must be named`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rename_all` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mtrx %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    rename_all(~ names(df))
#   A  B
# 1 1  6
# 2 2  7
# 3 3  8
# 4 4  9
# 5 5 10
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `setNames`

```
mtrx %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(., nm = names(df))
#  A  B
#1 1  6
#2 2  7
#3 3  8
#4 4  9
#5 5 10
```

Or use `purrr`'s equivalent `set_names`

```
mtrx %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  purrr::set_names(., nm = names(df))
```

---

A third option is `"names<-"`

```
mtrx %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  "names<-"(names(df))
```